# How to enforce user validation EXCEPT on server startup in meteor?

Tags: authentication, meteor

I want no user to be able to create users with the super-admin role, I want the only super-admin created by the server upon startup.  How do I create an Accounts.validateNewUser() function enforcing this?

More generally, I want all new users validated a certain way EXCEPT the one created during server startup.  How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When the server starts up, create the new super-admin user and make sure that this user has a unique key in its document. ex: `isSuperAdmin: true`. In your `Accounts.validateNewUser()` code (which runs on the server):

```
if ( Meteor.user().isSuperAdmin || Meteor.users.find().count() <= 1 ) return true; // only allow super admin to create users with exception for very first user
else throw new Meteor.error(403,'Forbidden');
```

You'll also need a *deny* rule for any attempt to set the *isSuperAdmin* key on a user.

Comment: How do you add this user's key before ```validateNewUser()``` fires?  ```Accounts.createUser()``` http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser
has nowhere to add this, besides profile which is public

Comment: Assuming you're creating the new superAdmin user on the server, modify that user document *after* you save it to insert the new key from your server code. I modified the code in my answer to create the exception for the very first user you create in startup.